# Run script if selected value is changed

Tags: javascript, php

I want to run a PHP script if the value is changed in my `dropdown`. The PHP script should run an `if else` statement. Is it possible to run this script, without a form POST?

Here is my dropdown:

```
<select id="data" name="data" class="select2_single form-control">
  <option value="1">Data 1</option>
  <option value="2">Data 2</option>
</select>
```

Here is the script I want to execute:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['data'] != '1') {
    echo  'Value 1 is selected';
  }
  if($_POST['data'] != '2') {
    echo 'Value 1 is selected';
  } else {
    echo  'No value selected';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Google AJAX ...

Comment: And those conditions will not work as expected

Comment: are you Need a Javascript  if condition or php?

Comment: An AJAX call (done from within javascript) allows to do a request to the server _in background_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can do this using just plain JavaScript:

```js
var dataEl = document.querySelector('#data'),
    outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

dataEl.onchange = function() {
  outputEl.innerText = dataEl.value 
    ? 'Value ' + dataEl.value + ' is selected'
    : 'No value selected';
};
```

```html
<select id="data" name="data" class="select2_single form-control">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">Data 1</option>
  <option value="2">Data 2</option>
</select>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: The code looks good, but I want to return an HTML code if value is 1. How do I need to specify that?

Comment: If you return html code, than you can use `outputEl.innerHTML` instead of `outputEl.innerText`

Comment: And how can I a specify the if value = 1 ?

Comment: In the event handler function you can get the selected value with `dataEl.value`.. 
Than just do `if (1 === dataEl.value) { // your code }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this js code for change value and handle post data at php end:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#data").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();       
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        data: 'id='+ id, 
        url : "dynamic_select.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //Handle returned data 
        }
    });

   });

});
```

Comment: And the content of dynamic_select.php must be the `if else`?